# nested methods testing using easy mock

Tags: class, junit, mockito, easymock, powermock

i am  facing a problem regarding class mocking in java.

I will explain the problem using dummy classes( to avoid project related security concerns)
We have a class  Employee

```
public class Employee {
public int netSalary() {
    int sal = totalSal() - 100;
    return sal;
}

public int totalSal() {
    // code to return value which is making db calls or remote calls
}
```

}

Now my problem  is that how to test  netSalary method without  totalSal method being called
i  have tried   expect().andReturn()  as well  as  suppress(method());

But both are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was done via MVC then your employee class should have a DAO that gives access to the DB. Inject a mocked version of the DAO that is called in `totalSalary`.

Per Comment:

This is based on the code you have above:

```
public class MyTest{

    private class TestableEmployee extends Employee{

        public int totalSal(){
           return 55;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt(){
       Employee employee = new TestableEmployee();

       int netValue = employee.netSalary();

       assertEquals(netValue, 55-100);
    } 
}
```

Comment: @John....this is not the thing i asked for. i mean we don't want to call the method although i appreciate your suggestion but bit apprehensive about this thing.

Comment: Another option is to create a subclass of `Employee` (say `TestableEmployee`) that overrides `totalSalary()`

Comment: can you bit elaborate this overriding thing with reference or example.Any pointers. but i dont want to change my original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). Mock the method:

```
when(employee.totalSal()).thenReturn(1000);
```

Comment: you forgot to say that `employee` should be a mock or stub

Comment: @michael   employee can not be mock bcoz we have to test the  netSalary()  method so we can not mock employee

Comment: Then in that case, these both the methods should be tested together in a unit test, because they both are tightly coupled together. You can accomplish it using in-memory databases like HSQL.

Comment: Mockito allows to create mocks that invokes real methods on call. For example if you create mock like `Employee employee = mock( Employee.class, withSettings().defaultAnswer( RETURNS_DEFAULTS ) );` and then you stub one method `totalSal()` like `when( employee.totalSal() ).thenReturn( 1000 );`, real call to `employee.netSalary()` will results with 900

Comment: @michael  actually i have that example where we can do this with the help of  mockito using spy and then  using when().thenreturn() thing but the problem is that we want to do it with easymock.

Comment: @AnilSharma easymock also provides partial mocking: 
`Employee employee = createMockBuilder( Employee.class ).addMockedMethod( "totalSal" ).createMock();`